# Improvising: Difficult to get going

Tags: guitar

When I improvise (guitar) I find that it can take me an hour or more to get going. Is the normal? If so, any way to improve it? And I'm playing solo with backing tracks at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean "to get going"? What happens? That's when you start to feel good or what?

Comment: Your question and potential answer could be a lot better if you explain a bit what you do and why you think the starting of a session isn't "going" but it is after an hour.

Comment: Agreed... what do you mean by "get going"? Are experiencing a mental block that's preventing you from improvisiong, does it take 1h to get "into the groove" of the track, or is it that you don't like the results you get until 1h into your improv?

Answer (score 5):

What are you doing for an hour? How long have you been playing?

You have to know enough music and technique to have something to say.
One philosophy is that impov is "variation on a theme".  So don't just noodle around but learn a song thoroughly, even learn someone else's solo on the song (original if it's a guitar song) then start editing, adding some of your own ideas, filling in spots.

When I was younger I would do this with Led Zeppelin.  Sometimes I'd pretend the band had 2 guitarists (like Iron Maiden) and I'd do call and response along with the solos (provided Page gave some space).

If you're playing with backing tracks I can't imaging what you're doing for an hour.  Are the tracks that long?  Before playing with backing tracks try the suggestion above, learning a song with solos.

Comment: +1 for turning off the backing track. I have tried something similar: play a few bars of a chord vamp then improvise a phrase with some licks, keeping it all in time so the licks fit the timing of the vamp. I think it makes you be much more musical rather than just noodling while the backing track provides cover for unmusical phrases.

Answer (score 2):

I can see 2 quite different ways:

A.

1. just by playing around with your fingers on the frets with the left hand (*hammer on*) you’ll find out and develop new patterns  and riffs  that you can use for improvisation.
2. Of course you can learn also the riffs from existing songs and exercise and copy other guitarists.

B.

The other approach is by singing the song and turn it for hours in your head your mind will suddenly start to build variations (try time change, swing, syncopation, triplets, change notes and passing tones, chromatic passages, scales, pentatonic, arpeggios).
Try to notate these ideas (real notes, tabs or just like *neumes* or visual signs and practice them on your guitar.

So you‘ll develop yourself a whole repertoire of variation patterns which you can use to improvise for this song also for all other songs.